# How do I put user input into a dictionary using variable names?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, user-input

I have to write data to a CSV file.
In one part of my code, I wanted to add user input to a dictionary and convert it into a `DataFrame` after that.

So first I took input simply by assigning it to a variable name, e.g.

```
fruit = input('Which fruit would you like').casefold()
vegetable = input('Which vegetable would you like').casefold()
drink = input('Which drink would you like').casefold()
```

It then keeps collecting input until the user asks it to stop.
But now I need to first display a certain row of this collected data, then sort that data, then display the sorted version. So I decided a simple way to do so is to put it into a dictionary, then sort it into a `DataFrame`.
I'm not sure how to do so with these variable names though, eg. if I wanna make one like:

```
data = {
    'Fruits': fruits,
    'Vegetables': vegetables, 
    'Drinks' : drinks 
}
```

How do I do so?
If you think there's another simpler way to add this info to a `DataFrame`/write it to a CSV file besides the dictionary method, please do mention that as well.

Very very new to Python and SOF, so forgive me if the question is unclear/stupid.
Also, please use simple functions/methods. Thanks!

Comment: there is nothing wrong at all with the code you have posted - that form of creation a dictionary will work.

Answer (score 0):

globals() is a method that stores the values of all current variables in the global namespace in a dictionary (locals() does the same with the local namespaces). So you can pass it a string with the variable name and it returns the current value. Something like this:
print(globals()['fruit']) 'fruit' being the key in the global dictionary.
So you might be able to do something like this:

dict1 = {'fruit':[],'vegetable':[],'drink':[]}

while True:

```
q = input('q to exit return to continue: ')
if q == 'q':
    break
else:        
    fruit = input('Which fruit would you like')
    vegetable = input('Which vegetable would you like')
    drink = input('Which drink would you like')      
for k in dict1.keys():
    dict1[k].append(globals()[k])
```

print(dict1)

Comment: using globals() is rarely a good idea - and wont work if the code snippet is in a function. Using a loop is not useful here - your code already knows what the variable names are.

Answer (score 0):

One way is this :

```
d = {}
d['Fruit'] = input('Which fruit would you like').casefold()
d['Vegetable'] = input('Which vegetable would you like').casefold()
d['Drink'] = input('Which drink would you like').casefold()
```

There is no benefit to using variables here - just use input straight to a dictionary.